# Line breaks in a string?

Tags: php, string, parsing

I'm requesting data from a server and when I echo the response out onto the page there are no line breaks whatsoever, but when I view the page source there **are** line breaks.

How is this possible? (i.e. How am I seeing line breaks when I view the page source?)

Using the `<pre>` tags I can get the data to show up with line breaks on the page, but I would like to parse the string separating the lines and I'm trying to understand how to find the line breaks in the string.

Make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: HTML ignores breaking whitespace except within `pre` blocks or if the CSS property `white-space` is set to [`pre`, `pre-wrap`, or `pre-line`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html).

Comment: Do you have control over the server response?

Comment: browsers parse html not plain text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not seeing line breaks because HTML doesn't render line breaks in markup. You specifically have to encode line breaks. The easiest ways is to replace `\r\n` with `<br />`

Comment: So even though "\r\n" is actually in the string, you're saying that when I echo the string onto the page the browser hides those characters?

Comment: It "ignores" them, @Nate. (At least in the situation where it would cause more than a spacing between characters.) See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#whitespace

Answer (score 1):

In HTML line brakes do not show up. If you want line brakes to show up, you use `<br/>`. In PHP you can use `nl2br` to transfer line brakes to `<br/>`

To replace line brakes yourself:

```
$text = str_replace( array("/r/n","/r","/n"), "<br/>", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

ASCII based line breaks have no impact on what is shown in the browser (with the possible exception of textareas).

To make the line breaks visible, try replacing the line breaks with `<br />` before or after the data is sent to the client.

For the server side try this:

```
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br />', $output);
```

Comment: Note that PHP_EOL means End of line. ASCII 10.

Comment: its used for matching or creating new lines/breaks, its specific value depends on the operating systems definition of a line break.